# como fazer o ng-bind-html de uma diretiva?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!-- ng-bind-html de uma diretiva customizado não funciona -->
<span ng-bind-html="customDirective"></span>


<!-- é renderizado -->
<choices-tab></choices-tab>

//Assim funciona:
$scope.customDirective = '<div class="alert alert-danger">teste</div>';

//Se eu fazer o ng-bind-html de uma diretive não funciona; não é renderizado nada
$scope.customDirective = '<choices-tab></choices-tab>';


angular.module('app')
.directive('choicesTab', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '../choices.html',
        link: function(){

        }
    }
});
```

ps. A diretiva funciona normalmente sem o `ng-bind-html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não consigo comentar, portanto, este texto não tem a intenção de ser a resposta.

O que tenho a dizer é que você tem que usar [***$compile***](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) na diretiva:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('choicesTab', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        templateUrl: '../choices.html',
        link: function(){

        }
    }
}]);
```

Aí sim você vai poder brincar de [**Inception**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception).

Mais referências:

[Using $compile in Angular](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx)

[Angular **ng-bind-html** and directive within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-and-directive-within-it)